# Access to the subnet of the OpenVPN server from the client side

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, routing, openvpn

i'am have server 172.26.8.231 in LAN 172.26.0.0/20 with OpenVPN server running(10.8.0.0/24, server 10.8.0.1). I want access host in server lan(172.26.13.14), i have added to server.conf:

```
push "route 172.26.0.0 255.255.240.0"
```

and iptables rule:

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -s 10.8.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

Server was restarted, but i still can't access to 172.26.13.14 from client(from server ok, firewall on 172.26.13.14 allow access from 0.0.0.0/0).

What i missed? Thanks.

Comment: Does 172.26.13.14 have a valid route back to the OpenVPN clients?

Comment: I didn't add it, how can I do that?

Comment: Depends on how your network is configured. Can be added on clients, or you can add it on the router that acts as default gateway. As things are now the reply packets probably go to default gateway.

Answer (score 1):

So your OpenVPN clients (10.8.0.0/24) has valid route to 172.26.0.0/20.

You can add the route locally on the client, or on the router that acts as default gateway. Note that some routers will send a ICMP redirect if the origin of the packet and the next hop is in the same subnet. Not all systems honor ICMP redirects.

Comment: `ip route add 10.8.0.0/24 via 172.26.8.231` on host 172.26.13.14 doesn't have

Comment: edit: doent's help*

Comment: Does the packets reach 172.26.13.14? What is the destination of the replies? Is IP forwarding enabled on your OpenVPN server?